# Удаление пробелов в середины строки

Tags: python

```
a=input()
while a != 'стоп':
  print(a,"!")
  a = input()
  a = a.replace(' ', '')
```

Согласно этому коду выводим слова с "!" в конце до слова стоп , однако у меня выводит вот так:
2
2 !
3
3 !
Между ! и словом есть пробел, помогите его убрать пожалуйста

Comment: `print(a,"!")` -> `print(a,"!",sep="")`.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Ну или так: `print(f'{a}!')`